# Forgot password send mail to the registered user java

Tags: java, email, forgot-password, reset-password

I am trying to create a link on clicking forgot password. Once the user entered their mail id and clicks the button, the user should check their mail for the reset password link in which the link is accessible of the specified time, Later the link will expire. Please help me with this. Twice I checked for reset password link and both the links are different. I am trying to achieve something like this.

> Someone, probably you, made a password recovery request from Big Moose Saloon account.
>   Please use the following URL to complete the password recovery. You will be sent
>   to a page asking your email address and the new password.
>   https://coderanch.com/forums/user/recoverPassword/a847177581eba10b67b4ced1ba172cf5
>
> Someone, probably you, made a password recovery request from Big Moose Saloon account.
>   Please use the following URL to complete the password recovery. You will be sent
>   to a page asking your email address and the new password.
>   https://coderanch.com/forums/user/recoverPassword/b1ad4d031395ab72da93e2ab6216ce48

How will i do this? Please help me.

```
 public static void send(String to, String sub, 
                     String msg, final String user,final String pass)
{ 
    //create an instance of Properties Class   
    Properties props = new Properties();

    /*  Specifies the IP address of your default mail server
          for e.g if you are using gmail server as an email sever
        you will pass smtp.gmail.com as value of mail.smtp host. 
        As shown here in the code. 
        Change accordingly, if your email id is not a gmail id
    */
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    // below mentioned mail.smtp.port is optional 
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");     
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    /* Pass Properties object(props) and Authenticator object   
       for authentication to Session instance 
    */

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,new javax.mail.Authenticator()
    {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
        {
             return new PasswordAuthentication(user,pass); 
        }
    });

    try {

          /*  Create an instance of MimeMessage, 
              it accept MIME types and headers 
          */

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user,"no-reply@abc.com"));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setSubject(sub);
        message.setText(msg);

        /* Transport class is used to deliver the message to the recipients */

        Transport.send(message);
    }
```

Comment: you can generate a key (GUID) like you can see in the given URLs after recoverPassword/
and every time the forgot password email is provided generate a new GUID and sent with link to user. 
If I am your user, and I attempt 5 times, 5 url/guids will be sent to me.

Comment: What is GUID and how will i generate a key?

Comment: using java.util.UUID class, UUID.randomUUID(); this method will return you a unique identifier

Comment: Ca you suggest me an example. Please I am trying to find a solution for a long time and couldn't find till now. Please help me with this. Till now I am trying to find with the above you have mentioned.

Comment: https://www.codebyamir.com/blog/forgot-password-feature-with-java-and-spring-boot on this link go down to PasswordController.java

Comment: @WajidAli Ok I will go-through the link and let you know, If i am having doubts i will ask you. Thanks again.

Comment: I am not using any specific framework. I am just using MVC. Is that ok?

Comment: You just have to see the code from this, inside the method where UUID.randomUUID(); this is pure java code and has nothing to do with framwork. You can utilize it. just as an example.

Comment: Ok. Then I will go-through the code and will implement in my code. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: If you don't get it from there then let me know.

Comment: Sure. I will let you know.

Comment: I have added the code in the first post for your reference. I couldn't understand how to add the remaining piece of code. Can you please give me an idea?

Comment: I got it `UUID tokenId=java.util.UUID.randomUUID();
            String path="http://localhost/PasswordResetServlet?tokenId='"+tokenId+"'";
            String link = "<a href = \""+path+"\"></a>";
            message.setText(msg+link);` and now i am able to generate the token. How will I insert in database? `CREATE TABLE userpwd ( confirmation_token varchar(200),Email VARCHAR(254), reg_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);` The query is for creating table with tokenid and mail id. Now how will i insert? Please help me with that.